# Only append if list item does not exist

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb

I'm pretty new to dynamodb and nosql in general.
I have dynamodb items that look close to this:

```
{
  "code": "BTA1",
   "events": [
     {
       "type": "abc",                              
       "date": "01/06/2021",                       
       "price": "100.00",
     },
   ],
}
```

I fetch new data and want to append to the `events` list **only if** the dict item in `new_data["event"]` below does not exist.

```
new_data = [
  {
    "code": "BTA1",
    "event": [
        {
            "type": "foo",                         #
            "date": "06/06/2021",                  # already in DB
            "price": "100.00",                     #
        },
    ],
  },      
  {
    "code": "BTA1",
    "event": [
        {
            "type": "bar",
            "date": "07/07/2027",
            "price": "999.00",
        },
    ],
  },
]
```

Here only the second list item event `new_data[1]` should be appended to the list (this is what I want):

```
updated_data = [
  {
    "code": "BTA1",
    "events": [
        {
            "type": "foo",                         
            "date": "06/06/2021",                  
            "price": "100.00",                     
        },
        {
            "type": "bar",                         #
            "date": "07/07/2027",                  #item appended
            "price": "999.00",                     #
        },
    ],
  },
]
```

But I always get all list items appended regardless of being already in DB. I ended up with duplicate events (here would get 3 events).

And here's how I append:

```
for event in new_data:
   response = table.update_item(
      Key={"code": event["code"]},
      UpdateExpression="SET events = list_append(events,:c)",
      ExpressionAttributeValues={
          ":c": event["event"],
      },
      ReturnValues="ALL_NEW",
   )
```

What am I doing wrong?